# Getting Error with system() in perl

Tags: linux, shell, sed, scripting, perl

'

> Number found where operator expected at ./scripttemp.perl line 5, near
>   ""sed -i -r "4" (Missing operator before 4?) String found where
>   operator expected at ./scripttemp.perl line 5, near "}" error.txt""
>   (Missing operator before " error.txt"?) syntax error at
>   ./scripttemp.perl line 5, near ""sed -i -r "4" syntax error at
>   ./scripttemp.perl line 5, near "s/[-.*-]//g}" Execution of
>   ./scripttemp.perl aborted due to compilation errors. '

I am getting this error running my script :

```
**#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
exec("sed -i -r "4{s/\{\+//; s/\+}//; s/\[-.*-]//g}" error.txt");**
```

Please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Why are you calling `sed` from Perl?

Comment: Because I want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your use of double quotes.  You cannot use double quotes "inside" double quotes unless they are escaped.  Instead you could either escape your double quotes or more preferrably alternate quotes by using single quotes instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
exec("sed -i -r '4{s/\{\+//; s/\+}//; s/\[-.*-]//g}' error.txt");
```

Comment: You may also have an issue in your regex (the unescaped "}" and "]")

Comment: Now I am having this error : >sed: -e expresssion #1, char 9: Invalid Regular Expression

Comment: Could you provide some example error.txt lines and what exactly you are trying to make the lines look like?

Comment: The thing is if i run : ~sed -i -r '4{s/\{\+//; s/\+}//; s/\[-.*-]//g}' error.txt through linux command shell  it runs perfectly but when i try to run it through perl script it gives me an error

Comment: The most basic debugging process: Reduce your script and try it, repeat till you've isolated the problem.